# Multi-column indexes and ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-order-by

The `PostgreSQL` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html) states that if we run a query `... ORDER BY x ASC, y DESC` on a table with an index `... (x ASC, y ASC)`, the index cannot be used because the directions do not match.

1. Does this mean that this index is completely useless, or can the database engine use the index to order the `x ASC` part (and then manually sort the `y DESC` part)?
2. What if we run a query `... WHERE x = 999 ORDER BY y DESC`, can this index be used?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, my guess would be yes in at least one of the cases, but you can always check your query plan to see what is happening.  If you see Postgres using the leftmost part of the index, then it's being used.

Comment: Never tried it, but why would you want to make a combined index in the first place? It's better to create two indexes

Comment: Note that the "directions" do not match only applies to multi-column indexes. A single column index can be used for sorting in both directions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Answer to question 1.

#### Postgres 12 or older

**No**, the index cannot be used, like the manual suggests. You can verify by creating such an index on any table and then, for the test session only:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Then:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ORDER BY x, y DESC;
```

Now, if the index could be used in *any* way, it would be. But you'll still see a sequential scan.

Corner case exception: If an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) is possible, the index might still be used if it's substantially smaller than the table. But rows have to be sorted from scratch.

Related:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns)

#### Postgres 13 or newer

Postgres 13 added "incremental sort", which can be controlled with the GUC setting `enable_incremental_sort` that is `on` by default. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-13.html#id-1.11.6.8.5.3.5)

> If an intermediate query result is known to be sorted by one or more
> leading keys of a required sort ordering, the additional sorting can
> be done considering only the remaining keys, if the rows are sorted in
> batches that have equal leading keys.

Corner case problems have been fixed with version 13.1 and 13.2. So - as always - be sure to run the latest point release.

Now, the index can be used. You'll see something like this in the `EXPLAIN` plan:

```
Sort Key: x, y DESC
Presorted Key: x
```

It's not as efficient as an index with matching (switched) sort order where readily sorted rows can be read from the index directly (with no sort step at all). But it can be a *huge* improvement, especially with a small `LIMIT`, where Postgres had to sort all rows historically. Now it can look at each (set of) leading column(s), sort only those, and stop as soon as `LIMIT` is satisfied.

### Answer to question 2.

**Yes**, the index fits perfectly.

(Even works if the index has `y ASC`. It can be scanned backwards. Only `NULL` placement is a drawback in this case.)

Of course, if `x = 999` is a stable predicate (it's always `999` we are interested in) and more than a few rows have a different `x`, then a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) would be even more efficient:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (y DESC) WHERE x = 999;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=83439d523eea6f94bccc69405ad7d695)* - Postgres 10

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=83439d523eea6f94bccc69405ad7d695)* - Postgres 13 (2nd demo uses incremental sort now)

Comment: Thank you Erwin for your great answers! Just a note: PG13 uses index for SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY x, y DESC; too. At least in dbfiddle.

Comment: @AntonBessonov: Thanks for pointing out! I added an upgrade for Postgres 13 with details.